# Distance between point and parabola.

Tags: calculus

Find the distance between the point $(p,4p)$ and the parabola $y^2=2px$ where p is a fixed parameter.

I'm having trouble figuring this, the fact that the point and curve is in terms of p is different to examples I have seen, and I've become confused, any guidance or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=p$ then $y^2=2p^2$ and $|y|<4p$ so the point $M(p,4p)$ is above the parabola in the first quadrant.

We take then the distance of $(p,4p)$ to the graph of the function $y=\sqrt{2px}$.
Let $A=(x, \sqrt{2px})$ be a point in the first quadrant of the parabola. The square of the distance between $M$ and $A$ is given by 
$$d^2= (x-p)^2+(\sqrt{2px}-4p)^2=x^2-2px+p^2+2px-8p\sqrt{2p}\sqrt x+16p^2$$
We find the minimum of $$d^2=x^2-8p\sqrt{2p}\sqrt x+17p^2$$
We have $$(d^2)’=2x-\frac{4p\sqrt{2p}}{\sqrt x}=0\Rightarrow x^{\frac 32}=2p\sqrt{2p}\Rightarrow x=2p$$
Hence the minimum of $d^2$ is $5p^2$ and the asked minimun  is $$\boxed{\sqrt 5\space p}$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The square of the distance is $f(x,y)=x^2-8py+17p^2$. Substitute here $x=y^2/(2p)$ and set the derivative with respect to $y$ equal to zero, to find the nearest point.

Comment: Having a look now. Thanks!

Comment: $y^3/p^2 - 8p$ ?

Comment: Yes: from $y^3/p^2-8p=0$ you get $y=2p$ and then $x=2p$ from the equation of your parabola. Substitute these into $\sqrt{f(x,y)}$ to get the minimum distance.

Comment: Thats what I did, fantastic, its much clearer now. Thank you!