# Distance between point and a parabola using Lagrange multiples

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the distance between the point $(p, 4p)$ and the parabola $y^{2} = 2px$, where $p$ is a fixed positive parameter.

So far, I have got  $\varphi=\left(x-p\right)^{2}+\left(y-4p\right)^{2}+\lambda\left(y^{2}-2px\right)$

and the Lagrange equations 
\begin{align}
\varphi_{x}& =2\left(x-p\right)-2\lambda p\\
\varphi_{y}& =2\left(y-4p\right)+\lambda y\\
\varphi_{\lambda} &=y^{2}-2px
\end{align}

I am then confused as to whether I do $\varphi_{p}$ or am I treating $p$ as a constant? After this I am not sure of the next steps in the method to find an answer as to the distance between the point and the parabola.

Thanks

Comment: Treat $p$ as a constant. The next step is to set the $\varphi$s equal to zero and start eliminating variables from the equations.

Comment: $p$ is a constant. For the solution see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564905/distance-between-point-and-parabola/).